# Internet caching

Tags: caching

For **Internet caching**, an update heuristic is to hold the document for a time that is proportional to the known lifetime of the object. If we follow a typical 60% rule, and we receive a response as follows:

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2009 09:23:24
Server: Apache/1.3.0 (Unix)
Last-Modified: Mon, 8 Jun 2009 09:23:24
Content-Type: text/html

Until when should we cache this object?

Comment: Sounds awfully like homework...

Comment: Uhm... depends on the content. How often does the site get updated? How much hard drive space do you have?

Comment: is it depends on the browser we use? say just visit yahoo.com and get 500GB hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can cache it forever, it has no set expiry. What a user agent should do when it wants to display the cached content is issue another request with an [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.28) header, which allows the server to return a nice, short [304 Not-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5) response.

Another way to look at your question is "I don't want to re-request it *every* time, what's a good heuristic to trigger those re-requests?". One suggestion would be a frequency based on a Fibonacci sequence, so that recently updated documents re-requested, but as they age, the frequency of re-requests gets less frequent.

The HTTP/1.1 spec leaves this open, [Section 3.2.2 "Heuristic Calculations"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.2) has this to say

> Since origin servers do not always
>   provide explicit expiration times,
>   HTTP caches typically assign heuristic
>   expiration times, employing algorithms
>   that use other header values (such as
>   the Last-Modified time) to estimate a
>   plausible expiration time. The
>   HTTP/1.1 specification does not
>   provide specific algorithms, but does
>   impose worst-case constraints on their
>   results. Since heuristic expiration
>   times might compromise semantic
>   transparency, they ought to used
>   cautiously, and we encourage origin
>   servers to provide explicit expiration
>   times as much as possible.